# Posting to friends wall using Android FB SDK.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the following code to post on a friends wall:

```
public void postFB(){
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "An example parameter");
        params.putString("link", "https://www.example.com/");
        params.putString("to", "1481597430");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        System.out.println("Complete "+error +"Values "+values);

                    }})
                .build();
            feedDialog.show();
    }
```

The scenario here is that I use a different fragment to login to facebook, using thier LoginButton and I want to post this message in a different fragment. While my app requires the user to sign in FB only on the first run, does it mean each time I want to post to a friends wall I will have to prompt the user to sign in first?

As on the second run if I try to post to a friends wall I get the following error:

```
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'session' cannot be null
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$BuilderBase.<init>(WebDialog.java:461)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$FeedDialogBuilder.<init>(WebDialog.java:626)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3.postFB(Fragment1_3.java:73)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3$1.onClick(Fragment1_3.java:255)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-15 16:13:06.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: For post method there is an code me/post, where repalce me with friends user id

Comment: No, you can post this in any fragment. You should use the "activeSession" paradigm the SDK gives you. You should be able to get the active session from any fragment (since it's a static), and use that in your web dialog's constructor. Secondly, you can initiate (or open) a session from cached information (see the Session.openActiveSessionFromCache method). If you call that in a startup fragment, it will open the active session without prompting the user or popping up any UI. Lastly, you should always check if the active session is null before using it.

Comment: Hi Ming Li, does that mean I dont have to implement teh uihelper and all other call backs in the fragment where I am using Session.openActiveSessionFromCache method? Is this method enough to get an active session, request additional permissions and post on a friends wall? Please elaborate as I have been banging my head against a wall since days now.

Comment: Here it is detailed and documented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660031/using-facebook-login-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#interfaces where you'll find a description on how you could use the share dialogs of the Android FB SDK.

You'll also find some example code here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkfeed

Comment: I read all this before, but however they dont show how to post to a friends wall, it only gives a share option.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void publishStory() {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            if(shareDialog.isShowing()){
                shareDialog.dismiss();
            }
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setMessage("please give permission by log in.");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                            .NewPermissionsRequest(FacebookShareActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog alertDialog=alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && 
                            event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && 
                            !event.isCanceled()) {
                        alertDialog.cancel();
                            finish();
                            return true;
                        }
                    return false;
                }

            });



            return;
        }
        if(shareDialog.isShowing()){
            shareDialog.setMessage("Sharing");

        }else{
            try {
                shareDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        this, "",
                        "Sharing..", true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();


            postParams.putString("name", shareMsg);
            postParams.putString("caption", shareCaption);
            postParams.putString("description", shareDescription);
            postParams.putString("link", shareLink);
            postParams.putString("picture", sharePicture);

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    if(shareDialog.isShowing()){  
                        shareDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    showAlert("", error.getErrorMessage());
                } else {
                    if(shareDialog.isShowing()){
                        shareDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                    showAlert("", "Shared on Facebook");


                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "1481597430/feed", postParams, 
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();

    }
    else {
        if(shareDialog.isShowing()){
            shareDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
/**
 * Checking Permissions for Facebook sharing 
 *
 */
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please define the parameters to Request.